# Why does `std::input_iterator<In>` requires a `value_type`?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges, input-iterator

I am trying to create a data structure for arrays of dynamic-sized arrays. Multiple choices are possible, the simplest one being `std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. However it is often not efficient and we would like to compress the data of all the inner vectors into one big `vector`, and have a `vector` of offsets to tell where each element begins.

**Example:**

```
  // encoding of : | 4.,5.,1. | 7.,8.,9.,2 |
  std::vector<double> v    = {4.,5.,1., 7.,8.,9.,2};
  std::vector<int> offsets = {0       , 3         , 7};
```

Let's encapsulate it ! Consider the following data structure:

(note: the code is neither complete, general or precise, at this point this is just to give an idea of what is going on):

```
  class vblock_vector {
    private:
      std::vector<double> v;
      std::vector<int> offsets;

    public:
      using iterator = vblock_iterator;
      auto begin() -> iterator {
        return {v.data(),offsets.data()};
      }
      auto end() -> iterator {
        return {v.data(),offsets.data()+offsets.size()};
      }
  };
```

An basic implementation of the iterator type is the following:

```
  struct vblock_iterator {
    private:
      double* ptr;
      int* offsets_ptr;

    public:
      using reference = span_ref<double>; // see notes (0) and (1)
      // using value_type = ???; // See below

      auto operator++() {
        ++offsets_ptr;
        return *this;
      }
      auto operator*() const {
        return span_ref<double,int>(ptr+offsets_ptr[0],ptr+offsets_ptr[1]);
      }
      auto operator<=>(const vblock_iterator&) const = default;

      // ... other iterator interface stuff that is trivial
  };
```

**This iterator works with e.g. `std::copy`**. **(4)**

Now let's say that I want to replace my old `std::copy` calls with `std::ranges::copy`. For that, `vblock_iterator` needs to satisfy the `std::input_iterator` concept.  In order to do that, `vblock_iterator` needs to have an associated `value_type` (required by the intermediate [`std::indirectly_readable` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable)).

An obvious choice would be `using value_type = std::vector<double>`**(2)**, but I surely don't want to give `std::ranges::copy` the freedom to use this type at its discretion in its implementation: it would be inefficient.

My question is the following : **why does `std::input_iterator<In>` requires `In` to have a `value_type`**? At least for copying it is not needed (the fact that I can use `std::copy` and that it does the right thing proves it). Of course, one can say : "define `value_type` to be anything, it won't be used by `std::range::copy` implementations anyway", but then why require it?

I am currently under the impression that `value_type` is mandatory for e.g. `std::swappable`, but not for `std::input_iterator` (nor even `std::random_access_iterator` dare I say). But the standard committee decided otherwise: what is the reason behind this choice? **(3)**

**Notes:**

**(0)** `span_ref` is just like a `std::span` with reference semantics (its `operator=` is "assign-through" and not "rebind to new array").

**(1)** In reality, the reference type needs to be a tad more complex to account for offsets, but it is not the subject here. Suffice to say, that it is possible to have an efficient reference type for this structure.

**(2)** And I think this is the only reasonable choice. At least a container is needed (`vector`, `deque`...). E.g. a `std::span` won't do because if we bother to save the value pointed to by the iterator, it is because we will modify the original memory, and `std::span` won't help us with that.

**(3)** [In the presentation of the `std::indirectly_readable` concept](https://ericniebler.com/2015/02/13/iterators-plus-plus-part-2/) (then called `Readable`), Eric Niebler goes into some detail of why we need `value_type` to be related in some form to `reference` to work well with proxy references, but I still don't see why we would would even need `value_type` for algorithms that don't need to swap elements (or store them somewhere). Yes, there is mathematically a `value_type` for `vblock_iterator`, but why require it if it is not meant to be used? (similarly, there is also mathematical `operator+=` for forward ranges : but since it is inefficient, it is simply not required).

**(4)** And other algorithms: `std::move`, `std::find`, `std::find_if`, `std::any_of`, `std::partition_point`, `std::lower_bound`, `std::unique`... So I think that there is something more fundamental going on than: "we are just lucky with `std::copy`".

Comment: The legacy input iterator concept also requires `value_type`, but in contrast to the ranges algorithms with constraints on the type, `std::copy` is not required to diagnose its absence. It will technically just be UB to use the type as iterator in `std::copy` since it violates its preconditions.

Comment: More Hyrum's law than UB

Comment: To be clear, `value_type` doesn't necessarily need to be a member of `vblock_iterator`. It can alternatively be defined in `std::iterator_traits<vblock_iterator>`. If you don't specialise the trait, then `vblock_iterator::value_type` will be used. I don't know the answer to the question for sure, but I would guess that it's in order for `std::input_iterator` to be a drop-in replacement for Cpp17InputIterator.

Comment: @eerorika Yes it should handle previous Cpp17InputIterator cases, but I am not sure Cpp17InputIterator handles proxy references to begin with (I know that this is not the case of Forward, and IIRC it is very constrained for Input).

Comment: It looks like what you need is [`std::mdspan`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0009r15.html), which should probably make it into C++23.

Comment: Not just `std::input_iterator`, [even `LegacyInputIterator` still requires `value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), so your `vblock_iterator` doesn't model input iterator even in C++17.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes you are right regarding `LegacyInputIterator`, so I deleted its mention in the OP. Regarding `std::mdspan`, I don't think it will work here since all rows (and all columns) must have the same size. The structure I am describing here is analogous to a sparse matrix in CSR format

Comment: (2) is wrong, you can mutate through a `std::span`, you would need `std::common_reference_with<span_ref, std::span&>` etc

Comment: @Caleth No. Example: suppose you want to rotate the first element at the end. You save it into a `std::span`, then put the second element into the first one, ... until the end. Then you replace the last element from the one you saved. Except that the values inside the saved element are those of what the `std::span` is pointing to, that is, the old second element. The values of your first element are now forever lost.

Comment: The basic answer to (3) is we already have 6 iterator categories, which *mostly* form a hierarchy of capabilities. It's relatively tractable to know if a given iterator works with a given algorithm. If instead each algorithm asked for *only* what it needed, we'd have dozens of categories in a web of capabilities

Comment: @Caleth Beware that with C++20, algorithms are not only relying on these iterator categories, they are using additional constrains. For instance, `std::ranges::sort` requires `std::sortable`, and `std::ranges::reverse` requires `std::permutable`. I am not advocating to add a new iterator category. I am wondering if requiring `value_type` could be moved from `std::input_iterator` to `std::permutable` (or somewhere else).

Comment: It might be as simple as the presence of a referenceable `value_type` being the distinguishing feature of *InputIterator* over *OutputIterator*

Comment: @Caleth Well it is true that `std::output_iterator` (or LegacyOutputIterator for that matter) does not require `value_type`, it requires `std::indirectly_writable`, that a `std::input_iterator` does not require

Answer (score 1):

`std::copy` requires a [`LegacyInputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) for its iterator types.  *It does not check this requirement*.  If you fail to provide a `LegacyInputIterator`, your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

A `LegacyInputIterator` requires that `std::iterator_traits<X>::value_type` exists because it subsumes [`LegacyIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator).

So your program was ill-formed once you passed it to `std::copy`.  The behavior of your ill-formed program is not determined by the C++ standard in any way; the compiler can legally provide you a program that emails your browser history to your great aunt Eustice and be standard compliant.  Or it could do something that happens to align with what you think the program "should" do.  Or it could fail to compile.

The `std::ranges` algorithms have slightly different requirements.  These requirements are far more likely to be *checked* by concepts than the old style algorithms are, telling the user with a compile time error.

You are running into such a case.

To be even more clear, you cannot rely on the *implementation* of `std` code to enforce the standard.

These types are required partly to make it easier to talk about the types in question and what operations on them mean, semantically.

Beyond the simple requirements like `std::iterator_traits<X>::value_type` exist, there are semantic requirements on what `*it` does, what `x = *it++` does, etc.  Most of those requirements cannot be checked by the compiler (due to Rice's theorem, they cannot be checked in theory); but the algorithms in the `std` namespace *rely* on those semantic meanings being correct for any iterator passed in.

Because the compiler can assume the semantic meanings are correct, the algorithms can be cleaner, simpler and faster than if they had to check them.  And it means that multiple different compiler vendors can write different `std` algorithm implementations, improving the algorithm over each other, and there is an objective standard to argue against.

For a `LegacyInputIterator` and types `value_type` and `reference` from `std::iterator_traits<X>`, we must have:

```
value_type v = *it;
```

is a valid expression, `*it` must return `reference`, and

```
*it++
```

must return a type convertible to `value_type`.

Not every algorithm need use every property of every iterator it requires that iterator to have.  The goal here is to have semantically meaningful categories that do not demand too much in the way of overhead.

Requiring that an iterator over stuff actually have a type it is an iterator over is not a large overhead.  And it makes talking about that the iterator *is* insanely easier.

You could refactor it and remove that concept, or cut the concept up into smaller pieces so that the `value_type` is only required in the narrow cases where it is required, but that would make the concepts harder to write about and harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but it does not explain *why* it is this way or *if it should* be this way. My guess is that before C++20 iterators, proxy references were not supported. So the `reference` type had to be a `value_type&` (possibly const-qualified), hence having a `value_type` was pretty natural. But I don't think that requiring the presence of `value_type`  to all non-swapping standard algorithms is justified if virtually all of them don't need it

Comment: @Bérenger I explained that talking about iterators is easier when those types exist.  That is their only purpose.  That purpose has huge value.  And no, input iterator `reference` for a `LegacyInputIterator` need not be `value_type&`; that requirement shows up after `LegacyInputIterator`.  `reference` must be convertible-to `value_type`.  Those sentences would be very difficult to say without a type `value_type`.  Could you design an entire iterator heirarchy without such aliases?  Yes.  These concepts are already hard, I wouldn't want to see what it looks like.

Comment: Yes sorry for `LegacyInputIterator`, I simplified a bit too much. Once again, I am not denying the fact that these `value_type` types do not exist in a mathematical sense, just that they might be tricky to materialize in code... and they are not needed by this code. Why not just make it only a semantic requirement that there exists such a value type? Such as `operator+= ` of `ForwardIterator` exists semantically as `operator++` repeated N times, without being materialized anyway

Comment: Another example would be Semi-regular : same semantic requirements as Regular, but `operator==` is not defined because it is tricky in some situations

Comment: @Bérenger `+=` does not exist intentionally on non-random access iterators, because the standard attempts to make expensive code verbose.  `std::advance(x, n)` is `x+=n` for random-access iterators and `++x` repeatedly for non-random access iterators; the standard could have had `+=` do `++` repeatedly, but *intentionally did not*, because then `+=` might be surprisingly expensive.

Comment: Yes this is my point : if the conversion from a lightweight reference type to a heavyweight reference type is expansive, why not do the same of what is done with `+=`? It would guarantee that e.g. `std::copy` or `std::ranges::copy`  does not use `value_type` while they don't need to

Comment: @Bérenger `value_type` is a type not an operation.  Again, it exists to talk about the iterator and its properties.  You may not like this answer, but that is the answer.  Provide it or have your code be ill-formed.

Comment: It is not only a type though : a `reference` should be convertible to a `value_type`, and this conversion is an operation. And it's this conversion that I want to avoid (i.e. I don't want to give the implementation the freedom to use it). By the way, any sane implementation of copy/move/find/unique has also better avoid it (let's say for copying a range of `std::array`)

Comment: And I fully agree : it is ill-formed, and I have to provide `value_type` to correct it (and BTW, this is what I am doing in my code right now). But this is not the point : the point is : why is it required?

Comment: "*the point is : why is it required?*" Because [some algorithms](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ranges_algo.h#L2927) that require input iterator need to use `value_type`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Well `std::min` is just a wrapper around `std::min_element` that dereferences the returned iterator into a `value_type`. So yes by its specification, it cannot work without a `value type`. But it works for the more fundamental  `std::min_element`. We can also wonder why `std::min` returns a `value_type` instead of a reference : it might be inefficient and that should be the caller's choice.

Comment: Note: And the constrained range versions do the same

Comment: "*Well std::min is just a wrapper around std::min_element that dereferences the returned iterator into a value_type*" No, `min_element` requires `forward_iterator` because the iterator it returns must be still valid.

Comment: "*We can also wonder why std::min returns a value_type instead of a reference*" Because returning a dangling reference is not safe.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Good point. Seems like `std::min` only works for two arguments or an `std::initializer_list`, but `std::ranges::min` works with input ranges and indeed it makes sense to return by value because of the input iterator case